# MS Access 2010 Run-Time Error '2467'

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, runtime-error

I have a MS Access 2010 application that is linked to MS SQL 2008 in the back end.

When I run the application, I encounter a run-time error '2467' - The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exists.

When I select Debug, the line points to:

Forms!FRM_MAIN_HOME!FRM_SUB_EDIT.Form.RecordSource =

I've run the query in the SSMS and works fine.

I've looked for missing references, and there aren't any.

When I run the application with Shift to present the forms, I get a different error: Data Type mismatch in criteria expression. This time  I don't have a debug option, but I suspect that this is the real issue.

One more thing: when I run this application on a different database, it loads with no errors.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

```
Forms!FRM_MAIN_HOME!FRM_SUB_EDIT.Form.RecordSource = _
   "SELECT V.VendorNumber, V.VendorName, T.DocumentNumber, " _
   & "T.DocumentDate, T.AmountInc, T.GSTClaim, T.GSTBatch " _
   & "FROM TBL_VENDOR_MASTER AS V INNER JOIN TBL_GST_01_TRANSACTIONS AS T " _ 
   & "ON V.AAVendorID = T.AAVendorID WHERE T.GSTBatch =" _
   & Me.BATCH_NUM & " ORDER BY V.VendorName"
```

When I run this code in the SSMS, it works just fine. Also, when I select a different database, it works without any errors.

Comment: Is FRM_MAIN_HOME open? Is it the start-up form? What is the query that works fine? What happens when open the start-up form manually and step through the code?

Comment: The form is about to open and I get the error. The query selects a record from a table. When I open the form manually I get the other error of the mismatch data type.

Comment: By what is the query, i mean please post the sql. A form that is needed should not be about to open, it must be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to some memory issues as the tables are quite large (and my machine is not the fastest...), but the error messages that appeared while MS Access is running (every time I click on a field, a tab, or anything really, I'd get the same error, just without the Debug option), is related to a table I have that MS Access didn't like one of the fields I had there.

To troubleshoot this error, I loaded an older backup, and started updating some columns and testing MS Access, until I found the problem. Also, I added some indexes, and changed the default time-out for ODBC to 0 (unlimited) in the registry.

That seemed to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am prepared to bet you are running this in the wrong event. You cannot use the Open event to refer to controls on a form. I am not sure why you are dynamically setting the subform recordsource.

The recordsource should be:

```
SELECT V.VendorNumber, 
       V.VendorName,
       T.DocumentNumber,
       T.DocumentDate, 
       T.AmountInc,
       T.GSTClaim,
       T.GSTBatch 
FROM TBL_VENDOR_MASTER AS V 
INNER JOIN TBL_GST_01_TRANSACTIONS AS T 
ON V.AAVendorID = T.AAVendorID 
ORDER BY V.VendorName
```

You should set the link fields like so:

```
Link child field : GSTBatch
Link master field : BATCH_NUM
```

Comment: the recordsource retrieves some records from the database to be displayed in the application. Wouldn't changing the code break the operation with other databases? Also, how do I set the link fields?

Comment: The link fields are properties of the subform control. A subform consists of the subform control and the contained form. How you access the properties of the subform control depend to a certain extend of the version of MS access that you are using. If you have a steady hand, you can click the thin line around the outside of the contained form. You will knwo you have the right control when you see link fields on the data tab, the control will be called FRM_SUB_EDIT.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I've set the link fields in the FRM_SUB_EDIT and when I run the application and select my database, I get a popup asking for the parameter GSTBatch and then for Batch_Num.

Comment: That is a different problem. Your code says Me.BATCH_NUM, where was it going to get Me.BATCH_NUM from if it is not available in the main form? When you paste the sql in my reply into the MS Access query design window, sql view, and run are you prompted for parameters?

Comment: Somehow, not sure how, Me.Batch_Num equals 1. This query is a couple lines after the declaration of Form_Current(). When I create the same query in MS Access (GSTBatch = 1) I get the correct record.
Can it be, given that the error doesn't appear when I use a different database (same structure) that the problem is with this particular database, and more accurately, the data in this particular db?

Comment: When you set up the main form, did you set it up with a record source or are you adding the recordsource dynamically to the main form?

Comment: I did not write this application.... I inherited it (without any documentation!) so wouldn't know how it is set up. I believe it is added dynamically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15850/discussion-between-remou-and-mikimr)